# Syntax Error on always the 3. embedVar on a Embed in Discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

So i startet with Embeds today and I ran into the Problem that always the 3. embedVar is marked as a Syntax Error. I have tried to swap to client instead of bot and changed much code but it still won't work. I really hope someone can help me here.

```
 import asyncio
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands

peppy = 'PeppyOnTop'

Token = ""

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as")
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('Peppy#1234')
    bot.loop.create_task(Status_Updater())


async def Status_Updater():
    while True:
        await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game("PeppyOnTop"))
        await asyncio.sleep(4)
        await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game("Peppy#1234"))
        await asyncio.sleep(4)

@bot.event()
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author.bot:
    return
  if "help" in message.content:
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Help", description="List of Commands", color=#FFFFFF)
    embedVar.add_field(name="Music", value="You can play Music with it", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="PF", value="Hypixel Skyblock Profile Checker", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="help_help", value="I am Forced to do this...help", inline=False)
    embedVar.set_footer(text="If u are having trouble dm Peppy#1234")
  embedVar.set_author(name="Peppy", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/901805828095483915/991805774693142598/packrat_66896305.jpg")
embedVar.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/901805828095483915/991805774693142598/packrat_66896305.jpg")
await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)

bot.run(Token)
```

Comment: Don't use `bot.loop`, use `discord.ext.tasks`. Also, fair warning, doing anything repeatedly to the API, especially at such a low interval of 4 seconds, is considered abuse and may get your account banned.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a traceback, but the following line is presumably the cause of the syntax error:

```py
embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Help", description="List of Commands", color=#FFFFFF)
```

The problem is here `color=#FFFFFF`. To use a hexadecimal int literal, the correct syntax is `color=0xffffff`.

Comment: It really worked thank you. But now in bot.event it says:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 28, in <module>
    @bot.event()
TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro

Comment: That seems like a new, unrelated issue. You should ask a new question on SO.